PyVoIP client doesn't answer to SIP OPTIONS sent by the SIP Server
I'm trying to create a SIP client that logs all the received calls.
I'm using Python with the pyVoIP library, this is the code:
from pyVoIP.VoIP import VoIPPhone, CallState, PhoneStatus, InvalidStateError
import time
import datetime

def answer(call): # This will be your callback function for when you receive a phone call

   try:
     print(call.state)
     anum = call.request.headers["From"]["number"]
     print(','+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")+', '+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%X")+', '+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%f")+',,,,,,,'+anum+',0662279775,,,')
     open('tmp.csv', 'w+')
     f.write(','+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")+', '+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%X")+', '+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%f")+',,,,,,,'+anum+',0662279775,,,')
     print(anum)
     call.answer()
     call.hangup()
   except InvalidStateError:
     print(InvalidStateError)
     pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
   vp = VoIPPhone('79.98.45.133',5060,'06xxxxx','xxxxxxxx',callCallback=answer)
   print('VOIP PHONE INIZIALIZATED: status = '+str(vp._status))
   vp.start()
   print('VoIP PHONE STARTED: status = '+str(vp._status))
   while(vp._status==PhoneStatus.REGISTERING or vp._status==PhoneStatus.INACTIVE):
     continue
   print('WHILE LOOP STATUS ENDED: status = '+str(vp._status))
   input('Press ENTER to stop')
   time.sleep(5)
   vp.stop()
   print('STOPPED VOIP PHONE: status = '+str(vp._status))
   time.sleep(5)

The registration phase is ok, the client is able to register to the SIP Server so I get:
WHILE LOOP STATUS ENDED: status = PhoneStatus.REGISTERED

When I call the number associated to the SIP account sometimes the call is received by the client and sometime isn't.
I made a trace of the SIP packet received by the client and I see that the SIP Server sends OPTIONS messages to the client but the client doesn't answer to them.
I guess that this is the problem: the server doesn't receive an answer to the OPTIONS messages so it thinks that the client is down so it doesn't forward the call to the client.
Is there a way to configure pyVoIP to answer to OPTIONS messages?

It seems like pyVoIP version 2.0.0 is able to manage OPTIONS link, now I'm looking how to install version 2.0.0 (with "pip install pyVoIP" I'm getting the warning that pyVoIP is already installed with version 1.6.8)
